# Subversion repository path suddenly changed

Tags: svn

After upgrading debian version (which probably resulted in updates of subversion and apache etc too) i can no longer access my subversion repositories at the url:s i used before.

Before all url:s looked like this:

> svn+ssh://user@127.0.0.1/project

Now i suddenly need to specify the full path to access it:

> svn+ssh://user@127.0.0.1/var/svn/repos/project

Anyone knows how to fix this? It was several years since i did this setup so i don't remember much about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Did this user have /var/svn/repos/ set as it's home folder before, if so check if it hasn't changed.

Another thing might be that there were links in the home folder of the user that are now broken causing the old path not to work.

Comment: Good suggestions. But i'm sure that /var/svn/repos was not set as home folder. And if there were links in the homefolder i guess the path would have been something like svn+ssh://user@127.0.0.1/repos/project. I'm sure there was not one link per project.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, not sure that this is how it was done before but it works.

Just follow the steps here:

http://blog.stranadurakov.com/2009/08/26/how-to-remove-absolute-path-in-svn-ssh/

Comment: This sounds more likely than my suggestions, indeed.